# Does every connected Lie group have a dense torsion-free subgroup?

Tags: lie-groups

For $ SO_2(\mathbb{R}) $ it is possible to find a finite set of irrational rotations that generate a torsion-free dense subgroup. For $ SO_3(\mathbb{R}) $ it is also possible to find a finite set of irrational rotations that generate a torsion-free dense subgroup.

Do all connected Lie groups have dense torsion-free subgroups?

Further Context about $ SO_n(\mathbb{R}) $:

Let $ R_\alpha \in SO_2(\mathbb{R}) $ be a rotation by $ \alpha/2\pi $. If $ \alpha $ is irrational, then $ R_\alpha $ generates a dense torsion free subgroup of $ SO_2(\mathbb{R}) $.

Let $ R_{\alpha,z} \in SO_3(\mathbb{R}) $ be a rotation by $ \alpha/2 \pi $ about the $ z $ axis. Let $ R_{\beta,x} \in SO_3(\mathbb{R}) $ be a rotation by $ \beta/2\pi $ about the $ x $ axis. If $ \alpha, \beta $ are algebraically independent then the two rotations $ R_{\alpha,z}$ and $ R_{\beta,x} $ generate a torsion-free dense subgroup of $ SO_3(\mathbb{R}) $.

It is my guess more generally that: Let $ R_{\alpha_i} \in SO_n(\mathbb{R}) $ for $ i=1, \dots, n-1 $ be rotations where each $ R_{\alpha_i} $ is a block diagonal matrix consisting of all $ 1 $s on the diagonal except a $ 2 \times 2 $ rotation matrix by an angle of $ \alpha_i/2\pi $ between the standard basis vectors $ e_i, e_{i+1} $. If $ \alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_{n-1} $ are algebraically independent then $ \langle R_{\alpha_1}, \dots,R_{\alpha_{n-1}} \rangle $ is a dense torsion-free subgroup of $ SO_n(\mathbb{R}) $.

Is it generally true that every connected Lie group has a dense torsion free subgroup?

It is worth noting that every simply connected solvable Lie group is contractible and thus torsion free. So all simply connected solvable Lie groups trivially have a dense torsion free subgroup.  $ \widetilde{SL}_2(\mathbb{R}) $ is a contractible, and thus torsion-free, Lie group. So $ \widetilde{SL}_2(\mathbb{R}) $ also trivially has a dense torsion-free subgroup.

Edit: This question was cross-posted to  [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449993/does-every-connected-lie-group-have-a-dense-torsion-free-subgroup)

Comment: Irrational rotations don't form a group. They're missing the identity and are not closed since composing a small rational to an irrational is still irrational but the existence of inverses would allow you to recover the rational rotation.

Comment: @CyclotomicField my bad for not being specific enough. It was never my intention to claim that the set of all irrational rotations is a subgroup. As you point out that is certainly false. When I said in the original question "$ SO_2(\mathbb{R}) $
  and $ SO_3(\mathbb{R}) $
 have dense torsion-free subgroups generated by irrational rotations." I meant generated by particular irrational rotations, not the set of all irrational rotations. Again my bad for being vague, I've edited the question to make the claim very explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, every connected Lie group $G$ has a dense torsion-free subgroup.

You can construct this inductively. The key is the following.

**Lemma.** Let $H \subset G$ be a countable torsion-free subgroup that is not dense ($\overline H \neq G$). Then there exists $g \in G - \overline H$ such that $\langle H, g \rangle$ is torsion-free. In fact, the set of such $g$ is dense in $G$.

To prove the claim using the lemma, start with $H_0 = \{1\}$ and keep adding elements that lie closer and closer to the identity to construct torsion-free subgroups $H_1, H_2, \ldots$. Then either the dimension of $\overline H$ will jump by at least 1 when going from $H_n$ to $H_{n+1}$, or this happens in countably many steps. Either way after reaching at most $\dim(G)$ countable limit ordinals you should have $\overline{H_n} = G$.

*Proof of lemma.* We use the Baire Category theorem. For that, we show that the following countable many closed sets have empty interior: The set $\overline H$, and for all integers $n,k \geq 1$, all $h_1, \ldots, h_k \in H$ and every word $w : G^{k+1} \to G$, the set
$$S = \{g \in G : w(g, h_1,\ldots, h_k)^n = 1 \text{ and } w(g, h_1,\ldots, h_k)\neq 1\} \,.$$
By BCT there then exists an element $g \in G$ not in these sets and such $g$ works.

Clearly $\overline H$ has empty interior because it is a Lie group of lower dimension.

Note that for every $n$, the identity is an isolated point in the set of $n$-torsion elements. When $G$ is linear, this is because torsion elements are semisimple and have eigenvalues equal to $n$th roots of unity. When $G$ is not linear, take a discrete central subgroup $\Gamma \subset G$ such that $G/\Gamma$ is linear, and then it follows similarly. This implies that the set $S$ is indeed closed.

Now if $S$ had nonempty interior, then $w(G,h_1, \ldots, h_k)^n = 1$ by real analyticity of $w$. But $w(1, h_1, \ldots, h_k) = 1$ because $H$ has no torsion, and by connectedness of $G$ and the fact that $1$ is isolated in $n$-torsion, it follows that $w(G,h_1, \ldots, h_k) = 1$, a contradiction to the assumption that $S$ is nonempty. $\square$